# Downloading a website which depends on cookies with it's javascript

Tags: download

I want to download an entire website with its interactive elements but it forwoards to another page when a specific cookie isnt set.

I tried using Cyotek WebCopy where in version 1.9.1 there is an option to import cookies but the website is still just empty when saved or only shows the page which one gets forwoarded to when not having the appropiate cookie set.
I tried saving it by just using the built in "Save As" function of Firefox as well as Chrome but the website is still empty. When looking in the JavaSCript Console I can see that there are lots of Errors, primarily HTTP 403 in GET requests for external JavaScript files.
The only solution that kind of worked was [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/save-page-we/) Firefox Addon which saves the webpage just fine but unfortunately breaks some interavtive things on the website and saves the website as a single file which, while this seems to be the addons main feature, is really annoying to me since I'd really like to get a better overview of everything and having all the images be huge blobs of text because they are base64 encoded is really annoying as well.
I also tried using wget and httrack which either generate an empty page or one which says that the content is loading or that the browser isnt supported. I'm really out of ideas by now and I hope that there is a simple solution, especially because I dont see how it can be that hard to download a website which is aleady loaded by the browser and theoretically even fully usable when, for example, going offline while having the website open already.